# Does ETH store a block tree (all connecting blocks) or only active chain?

Tags: go-ethereum, ethcore

Specifically I am interested in core-geth repository. Does it store a Block Tree (thus on single height it may store multiple blocks), or it stores only single (active) Chain (thus, on single height it may store single block)?